# Use procedure loop insert 200w+ records into a table which partitioned by day, msyql workbench always shows repair by sorting. Why?

Tags: mysql, procedure

The table is partitioned by day, and these records are spread in 30 days. Table *mydb.tbl_15mdata* contains more than 2000w records, so I want to split the table by month. The procedure encounters the problem and runs very slow when inserting data into the month table.

The procedure is as below:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mydb.add15mdataTa $$
CREATE PROCEDURE mydb.add15mdataTa()
BEGIN
DECLARE _id VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE _postfix VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE _tableName VARCHAR(50);

DECLARE _done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE cur_month CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(createtime, '%Y-%m') AS _postfix,id AS _id FROM mydb.tbl_15mdata  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(createtime, '%Y-%m') < DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '%Y-%m');

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET _done = TRUE;

OPEN cur_month;
loop_month:LOOP
     FETCH cur_month INTO _postfix,_id;
      IF _done THEN
         LEAVE loop_month;
     END IF;
        CALL mydb.create_table_month(CONCAT(_postfix, '-01'));
          SET _tableName = CONCAT('mydb.tbl_15mdata', '_', REPLACE(_postfix, '-', ''));
     BEGIN
                 SET @sql1 = CONCAT('insert into ', _tableName, '(id,createTime,power,generation,timeDST) SELECT id,createTime,power,generation,timeDST FROM mydb.tbl_15mdata a WHERE id=',_id,' and createtime LIKE CONCAT(\''
                      , _postfix, '\',\'%\') ');
                 PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql1;
                 EXECUTE stmt1;
                 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

         COMMIT;
     END;
END LOOP;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: is it possible that the statement doesn't use order by ?

Comment: The execution time of this procedure is determined by the partition key (what column is "day"?) and the indexes on your tables, which you need to specify in your question. Also, it rarely is of any use to copy data into a bunch of per-month.tables. You should probably add the reason you are trying to do this. There might be other/better ways to achieve your goal. If you e.g. are trying to speed up some query, it might be better to add an index that fits to that query. What is 2000w? 2 billion? 2 million? What data type is "createtime"? Doing "like" on a datetime might not be the best choice.

Comment: date type of createtime is datetime, day is a function of mysql which get the day of createtime. 2000w is 20 million. my goal is to speed up some query. there are two index which are id and createtime.

Comment: i have modified the procedure, user '>' and '<' to replace like and try to insert data by day instead of by month which would caused to go through 30 days partition.

Comment: Adding a composite index (on both columns together) "id, createtime" should speed up your procedure. That being said: you didn't explain why you are doing this. 20 million rows is not much, so maybe the fastest way might take just 0 seconds (not doing it at all). Also: Partitioning is not meant to speed up things, it is a tool to handle certain specific problems, so removing it might improve the speed too (although for just 20 million rows, it might not be that much): except for queries that only access a single day, mysql has to access 30 internal table structures instead of just one.

Comment: Sorry to reply for such a long time. I have found the root cause which spend the time. In the procedure "mydb.create_table_month", it will modify the partitions for the month table and the procedure will loop for five thound times.

Comment: But as you said above, 20 million rows is not much. In my business case, each device will generate a record every 5minutes. And there are 10 thousand to 30 thousand device. So there are 80 million to 200 million rows record in the table. Sometimes, I need to sum all the device data by each minutes. Is there any good ways for this query?